# Way out of date GEM file and new to ruby..where to begin?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

this was a project from 2015 ... so nothing has been update or made new....just dumped on my plate.

```
gem query --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.2)
actionpack (4.1.2)
actionview (4.1.2)
activemodel (4.1.2)
activerecord (4.1.2)
activesupport (4.1.3, 4.1.2)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
builder (3.2.4)
bundler (1.17.3)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
i18n (0.9.5)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
```

after running bundle install
So I'm wondering where I should begin to start getting this worked out.

Coming from a PHP/Python background....not liking this ruby ;)

```
bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    actionpack-action_caching was resolved to 1.2.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      kaminari (~> 0.14) was resolved to 0.17.0, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0.0)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.2)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.3, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.1.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    jbuilder (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.6.4, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.3, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "font-awesome-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    font-awesome-rails (= 4.1.0.0)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      font-awesome-rails (< 5, >= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
        i18n (>= 0.6.9, ~> 0.6)

    capistrano was resolved to 3.17.1, which depends on
      i18n

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jbuilder":
  In Gemfile:
    jbuilder (~> 2.0)

    jpbuilder was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
      jbuilder

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      jquery-rails (< 5, >= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)

Could not find gem 'mimemagic (= 0.3.0)', which is required by gem 'paperclip (~> 4.3)', in any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "net-ssh":
  In Gemfile:
    capistrano was resolved to 3.17.1, which depends on
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0) was resolved to 1.21.3, which depends on
        net-scp (>= 1.1.2) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
          net-ssh (< 8.0.0, >= 2.6.5)

    capistrano was resolved to 3.17.1, which depends on
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0) was resolved to 1.21.3, which depends on
        net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.5.2)

    passenger (>= 5.0.25) was resolved to 6.0.15, which depends on
      rack

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7) was resolved to 0.8.0, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.1)

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      sprockets (< 3.0, ~> 2.8) was resolved to 2.12.5, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.1, which depends on
      warden (~> 1.2.3) was resolved to 1.2.7, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.2)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      rails (~> 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.0.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.1.0)

    font-awesome-rails (= 4.1.0.0) was resolved to 4.1.0.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.2)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      jquery-rails (< 5, >= 3.0) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.5, which depends on
        railties (>= 3.2.16)

    js-routes was resolved to 1.4.14, which depends on
      railties (>= 4)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      railties (= 4.1.2)

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby

    aws-sdk was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.17.3, which depends on
        ruby (>= 1.8.7)

    byebug was resolved to 11.0.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3.0)

    capistrano was resolved to 3.17.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.0)

    guard-livereload was resolved to 2.5.2, which depends on
      guard (~> 2.8) was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
        pry (>= 0.13.0) was resolved to 0.14.1, which depends on
          coderay (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.3, which depends on
            ruby (>= 1.8.6)

    devise was resolved to 4.8.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.1.0)

    guard-livereload was resolved to 2.5.2, which depends on
      guard (~> 2.8) was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
        listen (< 4.0, >= 2.7) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
          ruby (>= 2.2.7)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
        minitest (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.15.0, which depends on
          ruby (< 4.0, >= 2.2)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7) was resolved to 0.8.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.5) was resolved to 1.12.5, which depends on
          ruby (>= 2.5.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.2)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.3)

    capistrano was resolved to 3.17.1, which depends on
      rake (>= 10.0.0) was resolved to 13.0.6, which depends on
        ruby (>= 2.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)

    rails_admin (~> 0.6.2) was resolved to 0.6.8, which depends on
      sass-rails (< 6, >= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
      sprockets (< 3.0, ~> 2.8)

    rails (= 4.1.2) was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.3, which depends on
        sprockets (< 4.0, >= 2.8)
```

And the GEMFILE

````
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jpbuilder'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
# gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem "passenger", ">= 5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-faster-assets', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'byebug'
end
# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
gem 'devise'

# https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 0.6.2'

# https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3'

# https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails
gem 'bower-rails', '~> 0.9.0'

# https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload
gem 'guard-livereload', group: :development

# https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload
gem 'rack-livereload', group: :development

# http://railsware.github.io/js-routes/
gem 'js-routes'

# https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby
gem 'aws-sdk'

# Action caching. Read more: https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'

# Dalli memcached client. Read more: https://github.com/mperham/dalli
gem 'dalli'

# https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.1.0.0'

# WYSIWYG editor for admin backend. Read more: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor
gem 'ckeditor'```
````

Answer (score 0):

This Rails version remembers the last mammoths so what did you expect? :)

First things first:

1. Double check you are not trying to build this project on the bleeding edge Ruby (3.x). Even the latest 2.x might be a problem with Rails that old. Google "Rails & Ruby compatibility" to check which Ruby version is recommended for this fossil and don't try to move too far ahead. Use some Ruby version manager to switch between versions easily (my choice is `asdf`, but more common `rbenv` or `rvm` work too).
2. If downgrading Ruby doesn't help, try removing `Gemfile.lock` (copy it somewhere just in case) and reinstalling dependencies. Bundler locks dependencies there to minimize the surface of dependencies' changes. This is a very good thing during the normal development cycle, but for "archeological excavations" like the one you have to work with this might be a problem. With the lock file removed bundler will re-evaluate the dependencies graph from scratch so most of the conflicts you see now should be resolved. Probably :)

Be ready that even after this, you might have conflicts that the bundler cannot resolve on its own (due to some older versions of dependencies that are unavailable anymore etc).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. See above to see the installed GEMS... appears to have the actionpack correct version installed however sill throws up.